# Migrate a library from 2.0 to 3.5 breaks app that references

Tags: sharepoint, dll, reference, sharepoint-2007

SharePoint app references a library that has always been on 2.0, recently upgraded to 3.5.  Upon upgrading and updating the referencing application I get a "Could not load assembly, an attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format".

How do I resolve this?

I thought this was an issue with target cpu, but the component is now targeting "Any cpu" and the issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you bring up the assembly info in Visual Studio, there is an Assembly version, and a File version. If you change the Assembly version, pages referencing the library will break, if you change the File version, it won't, or at least it hasn't for me so far.

Answer (score 0):

Can I assume the SharePoint server has the 3.5 framework installed as well?  Is this assembly in the GAC?  It could be that the strong name changed and you need to retract and redeploy the solution containing the assembly.